# converting variable \today to fixed string

Tags: table-of-contents, datetime

I have looked for two days to try to solve this one but there is something I'm missing.

My code attached (part of a lesson plan document) has lines to increment the start date from a fixed input value (the SetDate) to determine lesson dates in succession as either Tuesday or Thursday. This works fine in the Section headings, but when these are rolled up in the table of contents, the \today is calculated according to the set date at the beginning of the document rather than the saved date at the section in question. Thus while the dates in the section headers increment properly from Tuesday to Thursday to Tuesday etc, the dates in the Table of contents section titles are all the same.
I'm sure there must be some easy way to insert a fixed variable string in the section header so it shows the same in the table of contents but I can't see it....

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%

\usepackage{xstring,datenumber,advdate,datetime,pgf,calc,scrdate,scrtime}
\newdateformat{mydateformat}{%
\,  \dayofweekname{\day}{\month}{\year}, \THEDAY \, \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}
\SetDate[02/01/2018]
 \mydateformat{} 
\newif\ifthursday
\thursdayfalse
\def\mycmd{\dayofweekname{\day}{\month}{\year}}


\title{Course Title}
\maketitle
\footnotesize
\tableofcontents{}

\newpage
\part{Part I Title}

 \ifthursday\AdvanceDate[5]\SaveDate \thursdayfalse  \else\AdvanceDate[2] \SaveDate \thursdaytrue  \fi

\section{\underline{Section 1 Title} \\ \today}
    \subsubsection*{\qquad Learning Objectives}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item  by the end of this lesson, you should be able to: 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item demonstrate .....
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}

        \end{document}
```

Comment: Something with `\edef\StoredDate{\today}`, most likely

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `datetime` makes `\today` robust so that wouldn't work. Better to switch to `datetime2` which has an expandable `\today`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Didn't know about that fact. Thanks

Comment: Rather than using `\today` you could use `\edef\Today{\number\day/\number\month/\number\year}`. If you want two digit days and months you have to work fractionally harder: `\edef\Today{\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\number\day/\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\number\month/\number\year}
`.

Comment: for some reason this is not working with my example....have changed to datetime2 package but result doesn't recognize my \newdateformat, then commenting that out (and the SetDate) to use defaults, does not increment dates .... maybe some other incompatibilities with advdate package?

Answer (score 5):

The `datetime` package makes `\today` robust, so you can't expand it in order to parse the date information. Its successor, the [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) package was designed to allow `\today` to fully expand so that it would appear correctly in the table of contents, PDF bookmarks, writing the date to an external file, etc. (So any `datetime2` style must ensure this by protecting fragile commands.)

The accompanying `datetime2-calc` package (which can be loaded with `datetime2`'s `calc` package option) loads the `pgfcalendar` package, which can be used to perform conditional date testing and date calculations.

Here's a MWE that doesn't alter `\today` but defines a custom date which can be displayed using `\DTMusedate` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB,calc,showdow]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{dowdaysep={,\space},ord=omit}

\begin{document}
\DTMsavedate{mydate}{2018-01-02}

\newcount\julianday
\DTMifdate{mydate}{Thursday}
{% Thursday
  \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{mydate}{5}{\julianday}%
}%
{% Not Thursday
  \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{mydate}{2}{\julianday}%
}%
\DTMsavejulianday{mydate}{\julianday}%

Date: \DTMusedate{mydate}.
\end{document}
```

(This additionally requires that [`datetime2-english`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english) is installed, which provides the `en-GB` style.)

Note that `\DTMifdate` is just a convenient wrapper for `\pgfcalendarifdate`, which is provided by the `pgfcalendar` package (part of the [`pgf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) bundle). `Thursday` is a keyword not part of a string matcher, so if anyone needs to convert this MWE to another language, the keyword in `\DTMifdate` shouldn't be converted. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,calc,showdow]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\DTMsavedate{mydate}{2018-01-04}

\newcount\julianday
\DTMifdate{mydate}{Thursday}
{% Thursday
  \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{mydate}{5}{\julianday}
}
{% Not Thursday
  \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{mydate}{2}{\julianday}
}
\DTMsavejulianday{mydate}{\julianday}

Date: \DTMusedate{mydate}.
\end{document}
```